# Launch successive calculations of Abaqus

Tags: python, cmd, abaqus

I would like to launch successive calculations with Abaqus via Python.

Between each calculations i have to apply some python code to extract some results but i dont know how to achieve that...

To launch a calculation with cmd in windows :

```
C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands\abq6131.bat job=Fish1
```

So my command file in python looks like that :

- calculation1
- my code to extract some data
- calculation 2...

I try with :

```
from subprocess import call

path="C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands\abq6131.bat"
param_name="job='"
p="Fish1"
call([path, param+p])
```

But it doesnt work...

Comment: And....what? You want us to write this code for you? This is a **question** and answer site, but there's not even a single question mark here.

Comment: My question is how to launch a calculation via python...and i dont expect no more my dear Jonathon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using os.system, i think i can reach my aim...

```
import os
os.system("abq6131 job=Fish1")
```